# How to scroll a ListView without using NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

This question has probably been asked at least a dozen times in the past. Seen previous responses but still can't seem to get it to work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/colors_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I do have a workable solution which I do not wish to use since I am told there is no need to use `NestedScrollView` since `ListView` is scrollable by itself. Yet, I can't seem to scroll my `ListView` if I use it by itself. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?attr/layout_background_color">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/colors_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the big problem here that is you set `ListView` with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, it can not scroll because of its height always increases by its children.

Take a try with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. (Magic happened!)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/colors_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Sabbir! Unfortunately this did not work. The populated ListView does not scroll when I use the code you suggested.                                                       
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/colors_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Your nested scrollview always push listview to scroll down. Wraping listview or recyclerview with scrollview is bad way, your ui can be heavy. Try another method like recyclerview multiple view holder for better building scrolling ui with list

Comment: please support your answer with examples, code snippet or any documentation article